# Add highlight using ongr-io/ElasticsearchDSL package

Tags: php, elasticsearch, ongr

Can't find any example how to add [higlight](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-highlighting.html) to query results using https://github.com/ongr-io/ElasticsearchDSL

```
 <?php
  require 'vendor/autoload.php'; //Composer autoload

  $client = ClientBuilder::create()->build(); //elasticsearch-php client

  $matchAll = new ONGR\ElasticsearchDSL\Query\MatchAllQuery();

  $search = new ONGR\ElasticsearchDSL\Search();
  $search->addQuery($matchAll);

  //How to highlight results in title field?

  $params = [
    'index' => 'your_index',
    'body' => $search->toArray(),
  ];

  $results = $client->search($params);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <?php
  require 'vendor/autoload.php'; //Composer autoload

  $client = ClientBuilder::create()->build(); //elasticsearch-php client

  $matchAll = new ONGR\ElasticsearchDSL\Query\MatchAllQuery();

  $search = new ONGR\ElasticsearchDSL\Search();
  $search->addQuery($matchAll);

  $higlight = new Highlight();
  $higlight->addField('title');
  $search->addHighlight($higlight);

  $params = [
    'index' => 'your_index',
    'body' => $search->toArray(),
  ];

  $results = $client->search($params);
```